# How to prevent installation of USB drives which matches a specific VID or ParentID?

Tags: usb, registry, blocking, group-policy, device-instance-id

I know It can be done using Local Group Policy Editor in windows, but through code how to invoke it, I have not found any suggestions.
I noticed when I am changing a policy in the Local Group Policy Editor, in Registry Editor it is reflecting in this path:
"Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceInstall\Restrictions"
So, I have tried changing the Registry Path manually (because it can be done using code) but it is not working.

If any one have any suggestion or code snippet to share, it would be very helpful.

I expect a group of USB storage devices with a specific PID/VID/ParentID/InstanceID to be blocked from the system.